# Django form multiple choice

Tags: python, django

I am a newbie in Django and I would really appreciate it if you could offer me some guidance. I am trying to create a form that allows a user to tick one or more options. I understood that I must use MultipleChoiceField field with a CheckboxSelectMultiple widget but the Django documentation doesn't offer an example on this topic. I would be grateful if you could offer me an example and explain how do I handle the results. For example if I have a form with the options a b c d, and the user ticks c and d. Also how do I specify the choices(I don't want to use a db, a list of strings is what I have in mind)? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 29, accepted):

hope this helps :D

```
from django import forms


class Test(forms.Form):
    OPTIONS = (
        ("a", "A"),
        ("b", "B"),
        )
    name = forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
                                         choices=OPTIONS)
```

Comment: How do I make Django display already saved/selected values when editing the form?

Answer (score 57):

forms.py

```
class SomeForm(forms.Form):
    CHOICES = (('a','a'),
               ('b','b'),
               ('c','c'),
               ('d','d'),)
    picked = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=CHOICES, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple())
```

views.py

```
def some_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SomeForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            picked = form.cleaned_data.get('picked')
            # do something with your results
    else:
        form = SomeForm

    return render_to_response('some_template.html', {'form':form },
        context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

some_template.html

```
<form method='post'>
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type='submit' value='submit'>
</form>
```

results:

[image: checkboxselectmultiple]

explanation:

*choices:*

> The first element in each tuple is the
>   actual value to be stored. The second
>   element is the human-readable name for
>   the option.

*getting selected boxes:*

`form.cleaned_data.get('picked')` will result in a list of the 'actual values'. For example, if I replaced the `# do something with your results` with `print picked` you see:

```
[u'a', u'c']
```

in your console

Comment: Thanks a lot..it really cleared up things for me. I still have one more question. When I try to handle the results will I try to handle each element of the list as u'a' or just the string 'a'.

Comment: How take list of human readable names? I need take list of second option of tuple.

Comment: initial_values = ['a', 'c']       picked = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=CHOICES, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(), initial=initial_values)

Comment: What does the rendered HTML look like?

Answer (score 0):

you can check this https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-multiselectfield/

```
from multiselectfield import MultiSelectField

# ...

MY_CHOICES = (('item_key1', 'Item title 1.1'),
          ('item_key2', 'Item title 1.2'),
          ('item_key3', 'Item title 1.3'),
          ('item_key4', 'Item title 1.4'),
          ('item_key5', 'Item title 1.5'))

MY_CHOICES2 = ((1, 'Item title 2.1'),
           (2, 'Item title 2.2'),
           (3, 'Item title 2.3'),
           (4, 'Item title 2.4'),
           (5, 'Item title 2.5'))

class MyModel(models.Model):

    # .....

    my_field = MultiSelectField(choices=MY_CHOICES)
    my_field2 = MultiSelectField(choices=MY_CHOICES2,
                             max_choices=3,
                             max_length=3)
```