# How to include a link in CheckboxSelectMultiple label

Tags: python, django, django-crispy-forms

I am using CheckboxSelectMultiple as in the following SO link:
[Django form multiple choice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5747188/django-form-multiple-choice)

But I would like to add a link to one of the choice label. For example:

```
[checkbox] Option 1
[checkbox] Option 2 (link)
```

If I try:

```
CHOICES = (('a','Option 1'), ('b','Option 2 <a href="#">link</a>'))
```

The link is shown as raw text instead of a link.

Is there an easy solution for this? Thanks!

Comment: ^Ignore the part about translations, but `mark_safe_lazy` does appear to be the way to go

Comment: Thank you very much! It works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can mark you choices as safe, that'll do the trick:

```
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

CHOICES = (('a', 'Option 1'), ('b', mark_safe('Option 2 <a href="#">link</a>')))
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Work like a charm.